# Go update document using elastic search

Tags: go, elasticsearch

I'm using [go-elasticsearch](https://github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch) as a elastic search client.

I tried to update document using code from here [elastic/go-elasticsearch/api.update.go](https://github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch/blob/main/esapi/api.update.go)

However using the same code from GitHub I got:

`[UpdateRequest] unknown field [Title]`

So far I have only one document which looks like this

```json
{
    "took": 3,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 4,
        "successful": 4,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 1,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "posts",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "fc87941f-dc82-4fdb-9e04-460830e5f3ab",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "Title": "one two three2",
                    "Done": false,
                    "Created": "2022-02-09T11:51:59.027356+01:00",
                    "Updated": null
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

My go function:

```golang
func (postRepository) Update(id uuid.UUID, input inputs.Post) error {
    channel := make(chan error)
    go func() {
        post := entities.Post{
            Title:   "title updated",
        }

        body, err := json.Marshal(post)
        if err != nil {
            channel <- err
        }

        request := esapi.UpdateRequest{
            Index:      index,
            DocumentID: id.String(),
            Body:       strings.NewReader(string(body)),
        }

        response, err := request.Do(context.Background(), data.ElasticSearchClient)
        if err != nil {
            channel <- err
        }
        defer response.Body.Close()

        if response.IsError() {
            var b map[string]interface{}
            e := json.NewDecoder(response.Body).Decode(&b)
            if e != nil {
                fmt.Println(fmt.Errorf("error parsing the response body: %s", err))
            }
            fmt.Println(fmt.Errorf("reason: %s", b["error"].(map[string]interface{})["reason"].(string)))
            channel <- fmt.Errorf("[%s] Error indexing document", response.Status())
        }

        channel <- nil
    }()
    return <-channel
}
```

My entity:

```golang
type Post struct {
    Title   string
    Done    bool
    Created time.Time
    Updated *time.Time
}
```

In addition this is the only function which does not work, other function like: `AddDocument`, `RemoveDocument`, `GetDocuments` all works as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found solution here: [a-simple-elasticsearch-crud-example-in-golang](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/6drl/a-simple-elasticsearch-crud-example-in-golang)

Instead of using:

```golang
request := esapi.UpdateRequest{
    Index:      index,
    DocumentID: id.String(),
    Body:       strings.NewReader(string(body)),
}
```

use

```golang
request := esapi.UpdateRequest{
    Index:      index,
    DocumentID: id.String(),
    Body: bytes.NewReader([]byte(fmt.Sprintf(`{"doc":%s}`, body))),
}
```